# Cannot load driver class from maven dependency during process-resource phase (groovy script)

Tags: maven, jdbc, groovy

I have started to work on a script which is being run during **process-resources** phase (not my idea, it was like that when I got it). It executes sql script to clean db. I need to migrate it from command line tool to Jdbc.

Problem is that when I try to load driver I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

I have tried with drivers to other database systems but exception is always the same. Drivers are visible from eclipse as maven dependency and their scope is "compile".

I tried to load it both ways:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
//and:
def sql = Sql.newInstance(url,user,pass,"net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
```

I know that running such script during build phase is not a good practice but still would it be possible to have those classes visible at that time?

[EDIT]
It is possible to create an object of the Driver class, so it does not seem to be maven phase issue. Changing title to reflect that.

Comment: First wrong lifecycle phase (better [pre-integration-test](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference),cause it looks like a part of an integration test) and why not using [sql-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you need to add the jar that contains `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` as a dependency during the build phase.  That is, not a build dependency, but rather something available on the classpath during the build phase.

For this, I believe that you will need to add this jar file as a dependency to one of your plugins.  See this information in the maven book:

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/_configuring_maven_plugins.html#_adding_plugin_dependencies

Note that I haven't tried this and I'm not sure if this will work, but this comes to me as a possible solution.